# Magento configure product regular price being set to zero when sale price occured

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I noticed a issue on my configure product today. and Hope all of you guys can help me solve this problem. 
I am running magento CE 1.7.0 on the site.

Here is the issue link 
http://fishermandepot.com/best-deals/yo-zuri-surface-bull-gt-popper.html#.UOyhGKz5VHA

The issue happened as if you choice the drop down options for a sale item, it displayed on that page as

Reg:0 Sale:28.99 instead of Reg:33.99Sale:28.99

If you did not click the drop down choice, price display correctly.

I checked the back end, all the child product has correct original price and sale price. 
Add to cart function still has correct sale price.

I tried to go over the code. But not sure why it went wrong. Since if no drop down being selected. It will display properly once the drop down being involved, it does not work properly.

Hope you guys can help me out and solve this problem.

Comment: I noticed the same issue before on one of my projects. I have no logical answer for this other than a script issue. If any one knows the answer I would be very interested in knowing a fix for this! It happens on Mage CE 1.7.0.0 - 1.7.2.0

Comment: Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be an issue with your theme.

Try this solution but first make a backup of the original file. Just rename it to **optionsBK.phtml**

Replace

**app/design/frontend/[YOURTEMPLATE]/catalog/products/view/options.phtml**

with the same file located in:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml**

Found this here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/284168/#t393566

Comment: I could not locate options.phtml under my template directory. But there is a options.phtmll under the base directory. ??

Comment: Ok, if you do not have one under your theme then its already using the base options.phtml template file. That means this solution wouldn't work here. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I was hoping that would apply to your theme.

Comment: Try this just to narrow down if it is a problem with your theme. Temporarily change your theme back to the default theme in the admin area and see if the problem still persists. If the issue fixes itself then it would be directly related to your theme files and easier to diagnose. Let us know what you find out.

Comment: Without special price setting up, it works 100% correctly on the platform. However once the special price discount and custom options involved. The regular price being set back to zero. Anyone has any idea on this?